# Spring Data JPA JPQL queries on parent interface

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpql

Say I have a `@MappedSuperClass` like this:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class Rating
{
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="USER_ID")
    private Long userId;

    private int rating;
    ...
```

With a concrete child entity like this

```
@Entity
@Table(name="ACTIVITY_RATING")
public class ActivityRating extends Rating
{
    private Long activitySpecificData;
    ...
```

Then there is a Spring Data JPA repository like this:

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface RatingRepository<R extends Rating> extends JpaRepository<R, ID>
{
    public List<R> findByUserId(Long userId);
    ...
```

and this:

```
public interface ActivityRatingRepository extends RatingRepository<ActivityRating>
{

}
```

This all works great and I can call `findByUserId()` on any of specific rating repositories that extend `RatingRepository`. I am now wanting to write some JPQL in the `RatingRepository` that all the child interfaces can inherit. I just don't know what (or if it's even possible) to put after the `FROM` in the query. For example:

```
@Query("SELECT NEW com.foo.RatingCountVo(e.rating, COUNT(e.rating)) FROM ??????? e GROUP BY e.rating")
public List<RatingCountVo> getRatingCounts();
```

I can add this method to each of the individual repositories that extend `RatingRepository` but everything would be exactly the same except for the specific entity name. If I want to change the query, I'd then have to go to all the child repositories and update them individually. I really want the query to live in the parent class and not be duplicated. Is there any way to accomplish this?

I'm currently using spring-data-jpa 1.7.2 and eclipselink 2.5.2. I'm not necessarily opposed to switching to newer versions if necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Will it work if you will split query into 3 parts: start, entity and end of query? Than, if it'll work, in each interface you define constant like

```
String ENTITY = "ActivityRating";
```

And then you can use it like

```
@Query(RatingRepository.QUERY_START + ENTITY + RatingRepository.QUERY_END)
List<RatingCountVo> getRatingCounts();
```

BTW, there is no need to define public modifier in interface.

UPDATE: [here is described](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query.spel-expressions) another way:

```
@Query("SELECT NEW com.foo.RatingCountVo(e.rating, COUNT(e.rating)) FROM #{#entityName} e GROUP BY e.rating
```

Comment: That certainly works, but it does still mean having the same method on all the child interfaces instead of just having it once on the parent interface.

Comment: Perfect! This is exactly what I was after.